# SQL Server finding same records in two different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables called TableX and TableY.  Both are identical table with following columns

```
ID int
Sname varchar(256)
```

TableX has following data

[image]

TableY has following data

[image]

How do I write a SQL Server statement that show me all matching record that in TableX and TableY on the SName?

The results I want to see is

[image]

I want to match it only by SName.

thanks community
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SNAME FROM TABLEX
INTERSECT
SELECT SNAME FROM TABLEY
```

OR

```
SELECT X.SNAME
FROM TABLEX X INNER JOIN TABLEY Y
ON X.SNAME = Y.SNAME
```

OR

```
SELECT X.SNAME
FROM TABLEX X
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TABLEY
              WHERE SNAME = X.SNAME)
```